# Use spaCy to get the best possible match from a list for entity names supplied at run time that may be spelled differently

Tags: spacy

For instance, I have a list of companies such as:
JP Morgan Chase & Co
Bank of America
International Business Machines Inc
Toshiba Corp
etc.

I will get aliases that I may not know in advance. For instance IBM, JP, JPMC, BOA or JP Morgan. How do I get the best match in the list of companies for the aliases. For instance, if I do a similarity of IBM on the list of companies above, I get Toshiba from the large English model. Similarly, what would be the right approach to convert JPMC and JP Morgan to JP Morgan Chase & Co. And what do I do if an acronym does not have an embedding, eg. SSGA for State Street Global Advisors.